# Show Link Tooltip mouse over with keystroke

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, tooltip

When I use `mouse-over` on an Link (thanks to Tobias) it shows an Image and text. When I used `display-local-help` the image disappeared  (perhaps due to lack of space in the message area).
I want to start the `mouse-over` with any key. Therefore I need a function name.

[image]

Comment: If you have the answer then please consider accepting it. You can accept your own answer. That takes the question off the unanswered questions list.

Answer (score 0):

Not a real solution, but does do **some** of what you want:

```
  (defun my/show-tooltip ()
    (interactive)
    (let
        ((tooltip-frame-parameters '((left . 100) (top . 200)))
         (text (get-text-property (point) 'help-echo)))
      (if (stringp text) (tooltip-show text))))
```

What's missing to be a real solution:

- the `help-echo` property is not necessarily a string, it can also be a function or any expression.  I expect this to be easily solvable. See the description of the `help-echo` property in the elisp [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Special-Properties.html#Special-Properties).
- I don't know how to get graphic coordinates from a buffer position (need to put them as `left` and `top` in `tooltip-frame-parameters`).
- I have no idea if a `display` property on the string is honored by `tooltip-show`.

Answer (score 0):

Many Thanks !! It works. I had used pos-tip-show. It also works with a
button with tooltip-show. Here is the code for displaying a link with
image and text. I simplified the example a bit so that it works
without any additional functions. I wish you all a lot of fun! 
Andreas

```
 (defun display-local-help-als-tooltip (&optional arg)
  "Display of the tooltip with the keyboard instead of the mouse.
Template was display-local-help."
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((help (help-at-pt-kbd-string)))
    (if help
      (tooltip-show
        help )
      (if (not arg) (tooltip-show
        "No indication available at this point.") ))))

(defun wikipedia-tooltip (window object position)
  "Tooltip with image and text."
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char position)
       (let ((path (org-element-property :path (org-element-context)))(beg) (end) (text)(imgfile) (img) (s))
     ;;Here the image should be inserted dynamically.
     (setq imgfile (format "x:/Temp/milk.jpg")) ; path
     ;; The text is actually determined by a function.
     (setq text "Milk is very ...")
    (if (file-exists-p imgfile)
      ;; If a picture exists, show it with the text.
      (progn
      (setq img (create-image (expand-file-name imgfile)
                  'imagemagick nil :width 300))
      (concat (propertize " "
                  'display img) (format "\n%s" text)))
      ;; No picture available, then just show the text.
      text)
      )))

(defun wikipedia-link-face (path)
    '(:foreground "red" ))

(org-link-set-parameters "wikipedia"         
         :help-echo 'wikipedia-tooltip 
         :face 'wikipedia-link-face)
```